# Can't play Audio file from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, audio, dom-events

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("button");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].addEventListener("click", drum);
}

var drumSound = ["sounds\\crash.mp3", "sounds\\kick-bass.mp3", "sounds\\snare.mp3", "sounds\\tom-1.mp3", "sounds\\tom-2.mp3", "sounds\\tom-3.mp3", "sounds\\tom-4.mp3"]

function drum() {
    for (var i = 0; i < drumSound.length, i++;){
        var c = new Audio (drumSound[i]);
        c.play();
        }
       // Not Working
}
```

drum() function is attached to eventListener where button[0] should play drumSound[0], button[1] should play drumSound[1] respectively when button is clicked.

below function works fine if I choose not to loop but hard code [drumSound]'s  position.

```
function drum() {
    var c = new Audio (drumSound[3]);
    c.play();
   // Working 100% fine
}
```

I think there is something wrong when I tried to iterate through array.

Comment: The `Audio` constructor takes a URL. It's not clear if you're actually serving those audio files from somewhere, but even if so the URL almost certainly doesn't contain any backslashes - it looks like you're using Windows and those are the filepaths, but a filepath is not the same as a URL. (Check the console and/or Network tab, I'm expecting you'll see 404 errors for these non-existent URLs.)

Comment: I'm using file from local drive. File path is ok I checked it using single variable not a array, and file play the sound. I am using VScode which gives me a file path  with "\". So I had to change "/" or add an extra "\" to use the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your handler tries to play all sounds. I suppose you want to play a certain sound clicking a button for it.

It may be wise to use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation), using one handler function for sound (play) buttons.

Here's a snippet doing that (not playing sounds ofcourse, but you'll get the gist). The buttons are dynamically created from your array of sound sources.

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

// create the buttons
["sounds\\crash.mp3", 
 "sounds\\kick-bass.mp3", 
 "sounds\\snare.mp3", 
 "sounds\\tom-1.mp3", 
 "sounds\\tom-2.mp3", 
 "sounds\\tom-3.mp3", "sounds\\tom-4.mp3"]
.forEach(snd => 
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
  `beforeend`, 
  `<button data-snd="${snd}">play ${snd.split(`\\`)[1]}</button><br>`) );

function handle(evt) {
  // if the click originated from some button[data-snd]
  // start playing it
  if (evt.target.dataset.snd) {
    return drum(evt.target.dataset.snd);
  }
}

function drum(snd) {
  console.clear();
  console.log(`would play: ${snd}`);
  // if the sound is actually available, you would use:
  // new Audio(snd).play();
}
```

Comment: I do not want to dynamically create button. Suppose I have 10 buttons and 1 audio file for each button, total 10 file. I want to play respective sound when button is clicked.
Button 1 will play sound 1
Button 2 will play sound 2
Button 3 will play sound 3
Button 4 will play sound 4

Comment: You don't have to create the buttons dynamically  if they exist in your html.  In the snippet they are created because I didn't want to type the html for 6 buttons.